# Rails link_to to remove row from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models and a join table like so...

```
  create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  create_table "shots", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "comedian_id"
    t.string   "pic_file_name"
  create_table "group_shots", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "shot_id"
    t.integer  "group_id"
```

I want to create a link to remove a row from my group_shots table. So far I have...

## app/views/groups/show.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to 'Remove', groupshot_path(@group, shot), :method => :destroy %></td>
```

## app/controllers/groupshots_controller.rb

```
class GroupshotsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    GroupShot.where(params[:shot_id], params[:group_id]).delete
  end
end
```

Right now I am getting the error...

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant GroupshotController

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Here are my routes:

```
groupshots GET    /groupshots(.:format)          groupshots#index
               POST   /groupshots(.:format)          groupshots#create
 new_groupshot GET    /groupshots/new(.:format)      groupshots#new
edit_groupshot GET    /groupshots/:id/edit(.:format) groupshots#edit
     groupshot GET    /groupshots/:id(.:format)      groupshots#show
               PUT    /groupshots/:id(.:format)      groupshots#update
               DELETE /groupshots/:id(.:format)      groupshots#destroy
                      /groupshots/:id.:id(.:format)  groupshot#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<td><%= link_to 'Remove', groupshot_path(@group, shot), :method => :delete %></td>
```

For destroying a record the method name should be `delete` and not `destroy`.

You are getting error as `uninitialized constant GroupshotController` because your controller name is `GroupshotsController`(NOTE **plural groupshots**).

You have defined the route incorrectly  in `routes.rb`, it should be mapped to

`groupshots#destroy`(NOTE **plural groupshots**)

and NOT to `groupshot#destroy`

**EDIT**

In routes.rb, change the path from `/groupshots/:id.:id` to

```
/groupshots/:group_id/:shot_id
```

as you are accessing `params[:shot_id] and params[:group_id]` in destroy action.

Comment: Thanks, using the :delete method got me to the destroy method, however now I am getting the error  ArgumentError in GroupshotsController#destroy wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). Looks like my params are not getting sent correctly. Any ideas? Here is what I am seeing in the console http://pastie.org/8899563

Comment: Thanks Kirti, this really helped. I made edits to your answer, please accept them. The biggest thing I was missing was the arguments I was passing to groupshot_path.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in **routes.rb**

```
resources :groupshots #plural
```

If you delete them with the link given below,

```
<td><%= link_to 'Remove', groupshot_path(@group, shot), :method => :delete %></td>
```

It should work, it seems your controller name is correct. Problem with you mapped your routes incorrectly.

Also you can mapped delete action separately in your routes.

Comment: If you check the rake routes shared by OP, you'll notice that OP has defined resources :groupshots correctly BUT he has defined an extra route which is causing problem as that one is not defined correctly.

Comment: @KirtiThorat yeah...so problem is with the routes that he define. I can see that you mentioned in your EDIT.